# jodatime how to know if daylight savings is on

Tags: android, timezone, jodatime, dst

I have an API that needs the timezone. For eg. if I am in california, I need to pass -7 to it when daylight savings is on (California , PDT is GMT - 7) and -8 to it when daylight saving is off. But I am not able to figure out a way of knowing whether on the current date, daylight saving is on or off.

```
Date date1 = new Date();
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(date1);
double[] coords = db.getCoords(id1);
double latitude = coords[0];
double longitude = coords[1];
double timezone = -7; /* For Pacific daylight time (GMT - 7)*/

ArrayList<String> Times = Class.foo(cal, latitude,
longitude, timezone);
```

I have installed JodaTime and even there I cannot find a way. Please suggest if native java or  jodatime, either have a way of doing this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11389877/jodatime-how-can-i-know-whether-a-daylight-saving-occurs-within-a-specified-pe

Comment: Just a note: California is GMT -7 in standard time and -8 in daylight saving time. (Daylight saving is "on" during the summer (March-ish to October-ish in the northern hemisphere)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When you create a `DateTime` with JodaTime, you don't need to pass an offset.  Instead, pass the time zone.  It will take care of determining the correct offset, including consideration for DST.

```
// First get a DateTimeZone using the zone name
DateTimeZone zone = DateTimeZone.forID("America/Los_Angeles");

// Then get the current time in that zone.
DateTime dt = new DateTime(zone);

// Or if you prefer to be more explicit, this syntax is equivalent.
DateTime dt = DateTime.now(zone);
```

**UPDATE**

I'm still not sure exactly what you are asking, but perhaps you are looking for one of these:

```
// To get the current Pacific Time offset
DateTimeZone zone = DateTimeZone.forID("America/Los_Angeles");
int currentOffsetMilliseconds = zone.getOffset(Instant.now());
int currentOffsetHours = currentOffsetMilliseconds / (60 * 60 * 1000);


// To just determine if it is currently DST in Pacific Time or not.
DateTimeZone zone = DateTimeZone.forID("America/Los_Angeles");
boolean isStandardOffset = zone.isStandardOffset(Instant.now());
boolean isDaylightOffset = !isStandardOffset;
```

Comment: Matt, I want to know "given the time or date" if daylight saving is on. Basically the key thing I am looking for is the value of the argument "double timezone" in my code above. I have a date being passed to it. Using the date and the location I want to know if daylight saving is on or off. For eg. After november 2013 my timezone value should be -8

Comment: Well, you would first need to resolve the time zone from the location.  Joda time can't do that for you.  You need to use one of the methods [described here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16086962/634824).

Comment: I dont think you are getting my question. My location is california and it's static. I have to call an api "int Foo(double x)".  The variable x should be (GMT -7) or (GMT -8) based on the date i.e depending on if daylight savings is on or off. I want to know given the date is daylight saving on or not. If it is on I should pass -7 to the api.                                                                     I am not understanding how any of your answers is solving my problem.

Comment: Please read "TimeZone != Offset" in the [timezone tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info).  If all you have is an offset, then you can't determine if that offset is in DST or not.  You need a *time zone*.  Since you have coordinates, you can determine the time zone from those.  If your location is always in california, then your time zone is always `America/Los_Angeles` and there is no need to look it up.  There is also no need to tell Joda whether DST is on or off in that zone.  If I somehow still missed the intent of your question, please clarify.

Comment: Matt, thanks for the update. Your second update kinds of answers my question. The only problem is I have a particular Date on which I want to know if DST is on or not. So based on your 2nd code sample           // To just determine if it on Date "mm-dd-yy" DST in Pacific Time or not.                               
DateTimeZone zone = DateTimeZone.forID("America/Los_Angeles");                           //Assume date1 = "11-13-2013"
boolean isStandardOffset = zone.isStandardOffset(date1);
boolean isDaylightOfset = !isStandardOffset;

Comment: Thanks Matt. That solved my problem. I passed date November 4 2013 and March 10 2014. And it correctly shows if daylight saving is on or off on that date.

Comment: Does anyone have an answer for my question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26410962/joda-datetime-datetimezone  ?

Comment: you're short an 'f' in that last line of code ;). I couldn't get this to work using `Instant.now()` but that is fairly trivial to overcome. probably just a difference in versions.