# Java8 - how to know if daylight savings is on now

Tags: java, datetime, java-8

I need to find out whether daylight savings is on now using the new Java 8 datetime classes.
I found an entry how to do this in jodatime:

[jodatime how to know if daylight savings is on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16494174/jodatime-how-to-know-if-daylight-savings-is-on)

But how can I find it out in Java 8? (jodatime should be kinda similar but I could not find the corresponding method java.time.ZonedDateTime.isStandardOffset())

Thanks for your help

Comment: Why do you need to know the timezone? - Do you really need to know? Before you continue to write your code I would suggest watching https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-5wpm-gesOY&index=61&list=UU9-y-6csu5WGm29I7JiwpnA

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[`ZoneRules`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/zone/ZoneRules.html) contains the functionality you are intrested in:

```
public static boolean isDST(ZonedDateTime t) {
    return t.getZone().getRules().isDaylightSavings(t.toInstant());
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That's exactly what I wanted to know.