# Interrogate a ZonedDateTime asking if in standard time or in Daylight Saving Time (DST)

Tags: java, date, datetime, java-time, zoneddatetime

How to ask a `java.time.ZonedDateTime` object if Daylight Saving Time (DST) applies to its moment or if standard time applies?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Jon's answer is good. Just want to mention there is [ZoneRules#isDaylightSavings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/zone/ZoneRules.html#isDaylightSavings-java.time.Instant-) available.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = ...;
ZoneRules rules = zdt.getZone().getRules();
boolean isDst = rules.isDaylightSavings(zdt.toInstant());
```

And possible duplicate question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25638458/java8-how-to-know-if-daylight-savings-is-on-now).

Comment: I looked on ZonedDateTime, ZoneId and ZoneOffset, but failed to do so on ZoneRules. Doh.

Comment: @JonSkeet I just Googled "ZonedDateTime isDaylightSaving"...and I got lucky :)