# Joda DateTime DateTimeZone

Tags: java, android, timezone, jodatime, dst

+I have a time tracking app that uses joda DateTime to persist Start/End time with ORM-lite.
ORM-lite stores a Joda DateTime as long in database by using its millis.
Joda DateTime.getMillis() returns Milliseconds in UTC.

In a few days we switch from daylight-saving time to normal time and I'm not 100% sure if my app will handle this correctly.

To test it I tried to disable the "Automatic date & time (Use network-provided time)" setting of my device and changed the date to one that has normal time. Immediately the text of selected time zone changed from GMT +02:00 to GMT+01:00

I expected that all my time records are one hour earlier (which is actually a fail in a time tracking app) but this wasn't the case.
When I set the time zone to e.g. Abu Dhabi GMT +4:00 all my time records are two hours later.
This makes sense to me because the entries where created with my default time zone which is GMT +02:00.
Why isn’t this the case when I switch from daylight-saving time to normal time?

Cheers,
Stefan

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking.  Please provide example code, and specific actual and expected values including timestamps and time zones involved.  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I already found the answer and posted it below.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I had a wrong understanding of how things work.

Sample:

```
DateTime dtNow = new DateTime(1414479634046);
```

I thought that "dtNow" would change when switching from normal time to DST. I thought that DST behalves like a separate time zone but this isn't the case. 
When a DateTime is "restored" from Millis Joda looks at the date and determines if it is normal or DST.