# What is the Joda equivalent of Calendar get DST Offset

Tags: java, calendar, jodatime

I am replacing some Jdk 1.6 Calendar usage with Joda ..

I am looking for how to implement/replace the two following methods with Joda

```
public int getDstOffSet(long millis) {  
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.clear();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(millis);
    return calendar.get(Calendar.DST_OFFSET);
}

public int getZoneOffset(long millis) {     
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.clear();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(millis);
    return calendar.get(Calendar.ZONE_OFFSET);
}
```

Comment: If there is no constraint on JDK version try 1.8 it has this new package java.time :) :)

Answer (score 1):

Joda has a `DateTimeZone` class with these functions http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTimeZone.html

In particular, `isStandardOffset` will tell you if you're in DST or not, and then you can use `getOffset` or `getStandardOffset`.

This question [jodatime how to know if daylight savings is on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16494174/jodatime-how-to-know-if-daylight-savings-is-on) has some examples.