# Issue with inDaylightTime() and determing if a date is in daylight savings time

Tags: java, timezone, dst

Have been beating my head against this and not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

I am testing out the inDaylightTime() method for a certain time zone but it is returning "false" when it should be returning "true" in this case.

```
import java.util.TimeZone;
import java.util.Date;

public class TimeZoneDemo {
    public static void main( String args[] ){

        Date date = new Date(1380931200); // Sat, 05 Oct 2013, within daylight savings time.

        System.out.println("In daylight saving time: " + TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT-8:00").inDaylightTime(date));
    }    
}
```

This code keeps printing "false" when it seems clear that the result should be "true".

What am I missing here? Would appreciate any guidance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're specifying a time zone of `GMT-8:00` - that's a fixed time zone, which is 8 hours behind of UTC *permanently*. It doesn't observe daylight saving time.

If you actually meant Pacific Time, you should specify `America/Los_Angeles` as the time zone ID. Bear in mind that different time zones switch between standard and daylight saving time at different times of the year.

Additionally, `new Date(1380931200)` is actually in January 1970 - you meant `new Date(1380931200000L)` - don't forget that the number is *milliseconds* since the Unix epoch, not *seconds*.

Comment: Very interesting, thanks. Unfortunately I am still getting "false" with either "America/Los_Angeles" or "PST".

Comment: @kennym: See my edit - your `Date` was wrong too. Note that really "PST" should never show up as daylight saving time either, as PST stands for Pacific *Standard* Time. Unfortunately the abbreviation is often misused to mean Pacific Time, and it looks like the built-in time zone database follows that.

Comment: Thank you very much. Very informative response. I did indeed have the date wrong. Works fine now.

Answer (score 2):

The [answer by Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19864118/642706) is correct.

### In Joda-Time

Just for fun, below is the solution in source-code using the third-party libary [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) 2.3 in Java 7.

### Details

The [DateTimeZone](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTimeZone.html) class has a method, [isStandardOffset](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTimeZone.html#isStandardOffset%28long%29). The only trick is that the method takes a long, the milliseconds backing the DateTime instance, accessed by calling [DateTime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) class‘ superclass‘ ([BaseDateTime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/base/BaseDateTime.html)) method [getMillis](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/base/BaseDateTime.html#getMillis%28%29).

### Example Source Code

```
// © 2013 Basil Bourque. This source code may be used freely forever by anyone taking full responsibility for doing so.

org.joda.time.DateTimeZone losAngelesTimeZone = org.joda.time.DateTimeZone.forID("America/Los_Angeles");
org.joda.time.DateTime theSecondAt6PM = new org.joda.time.DateTime( 2013, 11, 2, 18, 0, losAngelesTimeZone ) ;
org.joda.time.DateTime theThirdAt6PM = new org.joda.time.DateTime( 2013, 11, 3, 18, 0, losAngelesTimeZone ) ; // Day when DST ends.

System.out.println("This datetime 'theSecondAt6PM': " + theSecondAt6PM + " is in DST: " + losAngelesTimeZone.isStandardOffset(theSecondAt6PM.getMillis()));
System.out.println("This datetime 'theThirdAt6PM': " + theThirdAt6PM + " is in DST: " + losAngelesTimeZone.isStandardOffset(theThirdAt6PM.getMillis()));
```

When run, note the difference in offset from UTC (-7 versus -8)…

```
This datetime 'theSecondAt6PM': 2013-11-02T18:00:00.000-07:00 is in DST: false
This datetime 'theThirdAt6PM': 2013-11-03T18:00:00.000-08:00 is in DST: true
```

About Joda-Time…

```
// Joda-Time - The popular alternative to Sun/Oracle's notoriously bad date, time, and calendar classes bundled with Java 7 and earlier.
// http://www.joda.org/joda-time/

// Joda-Time will become outmoded by the JSR 310 Date and Time API introduced in Java 8.
// JSR 310 was inspired by Joda-Time but is not directly based on it.
// http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310

// By default, Joda-Time produces strings in the standard ISO 8601 format.
// https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601

// About Daylight Saving Time (DST): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time

// Time Zone list: http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/timezones.html
```